# Xcode Missing required module 'SQLiteObjc' with Sqlite.swift

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I am using SQLite.swift to connect to a database but am getting "Missing required module 'SQLiteObjc'" on the import of SQLite.

[image]

I believe I have connected it properly. [image]

Here is another screenshot I took. It seems to be reading the SQLiteObjc module but it still throws the error. Help somebody please :((

[image]
Is there anything else I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it just in case anybody reads this and is having the same problem.

My problem was that I was manually installing SQLite.swift.

Instead I removed the framework and then did Add Package Dependency via the github URL.

I am no longer getting the error. Silly me.