# Xcode Previews fail with: "missing required module 'SQLiteObjc'"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite.swift

Although I can compile and run my project using SQLite.swift, I can't preview views that are in a local package.

An issue was recently fixed for Carthage installs:

https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/1150

I tried adding: `${SRCROOT}/SQLiteObjc` to the Swift Compiler Search Paths but that didn't help.

This problem occurs on an M1 MacBookPro running Monterey 12.5.1 using Xcode 13.4.1 as well as the just released Xcode 14.0 (14A309) running Monterey 12.6.

In my Package.swift file I have:

```swift
       .package(url: "https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git", from: "0.13.2"),
```

which resolves to version 0.13.3

I looked through many related questions -- this is the most recent mention, but it did not solve my problem:
[Xcode Missing required module 'SQLiteObjc' with Sqlite.swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60715863/xcode-missing-required-module-sqliteobjc-with-sqlite-swift)

Comment: Beta software problems should better be discussed on Apple developer  forums .

Comment: This problem exists on all production versions as well. I was providing context.  I've updated my question.